# clipping Tikzpicture within math

Tags: tikz-pgf

Every time I try to clip a Tikzpicture within math environments (*id est*, `\begin{equation}\end{equation}`, `[]` or `$$`) I get the following error

> Package tikz Error: Extra options not allowed for clipping path command.

Here is the exact code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\usetikzlibrary{knots,intersections,decorations.pathreplacing,hobby,arrows,patterns}
\tikzset{every path/.style={black,thick}, every node/.style={transform shape, knot crossing, inner sep=2.5pt}}

\begin{document}

\[ \epsilon\left(\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
 \clip (-1.5,-0.7)--(-1.5,0.7)--(1.5,0.7)--(1.5,-0.7)--(-1.5,-0.7)--cycle;
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-0.3cm]
   \draw[->,thin] (-1,-1)--(1,1);
   \draw[ultra thick,double distance=0.4pt,double=black,white] (-1,1)--(1,-1);
   \draw[->,thin] (-1,1)--(1,-1);
  \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}\right) \]

\end{document}
```

I saw [Drawing the rules for the bracket polynomial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306004/drawing-the-rules-for-the-bracket-polynomial) and got some ideas on how to fix my code. More specifically, following @egreg's answer by defining macros for the picture. However, I have a lot of knot diagrams drawn in mathematical environments, and most are scaled differently. The answer given by @GuM looked useful, but I did not understand how to implement it.

tl;dr: what is the best method to clip tikzpictures that are surrounded by mathematical environments, given that most are scaled differently?

edit: I am assuming it has something to do with the following line of code I have
`\tikzset{every path/.style={black,thick}, every node/.style={transform shape, knot crossing, inner sep=2.5pt}}`

edit2: When I try adding `\tikzset{every path/.style={}}` before the clip, and `\tikzset{every path={black,thick}}` after the clip, it does remove the error. However, it does not end up drawing all diagrams properly. For instance,

```
\begin{align*}
  \left\langle\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.005]
  \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
  \clip (0,0)--(150,0)--(150,100)--(0,100);
  \tikzset{every path={black,thick}}
   \begin{scope}[yshift=-70cm]
    \draw[thin]    (98.5,132) .. controls (48.07,199.48) and (-22.7,112.44) .. (13.82,70.28) .. controls (26.55,55.59) and (52.31,46.35) .. (96.5,51) ;
    \draw[thin]    (44.5,39) .. controls (78.5,-45) and (130.5,45) .. (114.5,102) ;
    \draw[thin]   (127.5,58) .. controls (195.69,97.4) and (107.74,133.35) .. (64.59,109.76) .. controls (50.78,102.21) and (41.56,88.57) .. (43.5,67) ;
   \end{scope}%
  \end{tikzpicture}\right\rangle 
\end{align*}
```

removes some curves. Not sure why.

Comment: I cannot get the same error. Could you make your example complete (starts with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`)?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Sorry about that, I added the complete code now!

Comment: As far as I can see, the issue is due to `every path/.style={black,thick}`

Comment: @egreg, yeah I assumed so. But how do I change my code now without messing up any other knot diagram I have? Also, if you do remove ```every path/.style={black,thick}``` the diagram looks a lot different. So, I am not really sure.

Comment: You could state `\tikzset{every path/.style={}}` inside the `tikzpicture` before doing `\clip`. I see no difference whether or not I reinstate `\tikzset{every path={black,thick}` after the `\clip` line.

Comment: @egreg I added an edit2 to the question, it's a reply to your suggestion!

Comment: In your edit2, `\tikzset{every path={black,thick}}` should be `\tikzset{every path/.style={black,thick}}`.

Comment: Why do you need `clip` in the first place? The line ends look better if the sloped lines are not clipped horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot to answer my question. @egreg's comment fixed the mistake.

I first made a new command to use:

```
\newcommand{\knotsinmath}[1]{%
 \tikzset{every path/.style={}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]
  #1
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Then, this works perfectly fine. The problem I was facing back then happened to do with the clip itself, but this also makes the error go away.

```
\begin{align*}
  \left\langle\knotsinmath{\begin{scope}[scale=0.005,yshift=-70cm]
   \clip (0,0)--(160,0)--(160,160)--(0,160)--cycle;
   \draw[thin]    (98.5,132) .. controls (48.07,199.48) and (-22.7,112.44) .. (13.82,70.28) .. controls (26.55,55.59) and (52.31,46.35) .. (96.5,51) ;
   \draw[thin]    (44.5,39) .. controls (78.5,-45) and (130.5,45) .. (114.5,102) ;
   \draw[thin]   (127.5,58) .. controls (195.69,97.4) and (107.74,133.35) .. (64.59,109.76) .. controls (50.78,102.21) and (41.56,88.57) .. (43.5,67) ;
   \end{scope}}\right\rangle
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that error is really helpful, or should it be changed to warning by applying following patch?

```tex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\tikz@finish
  {\tikzerror{Extra options not allowed for clipping path command.}}
  {\PackageWarning{tikz}{Extra options not allowed for clipping path command.}}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

IMOH, discarding unused `\tikz@options` in clip mode won't cause severe problems.