# Vertically align tikzpicture inside angle brackets

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tikz-knots

I want to vertically align a TikZ image inside angled brackets. I am not able to do it by adding `yshift` arguments to the `knot` environment or to the `\draw` or `\strand` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, decorations, arrows.meta, decorations.markings, bending, knots, hobby, spath3, intersections}

\newcommand{\KP}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]
        #1
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\KPthirtyoneone}{
    \KP{
        \begin{knot}[flip crossing=2, consider self intersections = true, clip width = 5, ignore endpoint intersections=false]
            \draw[scale=0.6, line width=0.6pt] (0,1) .. controls (0.5,0.8) .. (1,1);
            \strand[scale=0.6, line width=0.6pt, looseness=1.4] (0,0) to [out=0,in=0] (0.5,0.7) to [out=180,in=180] (1,0);
        \end{knot}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\[\Bigl\langle\hspace{-6pt}\vcenter{\hbox{\KPthirtyoneone}}\hspace{-6pt}\Bigr\rangle\]

\end{document}
```

I have taken some of the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306010/128462. It produces the following output:

[image: kpthirtyone]

How do I vertically center the image inside the brackets?

Comment: There appears to be a [bug with `ignore endpoint intersections = false`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3/issues/26) because it adds [space to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WATZ.png) that's unwanted. If it wasn't, I'd propose `baseline={([yshift=+-\fontdimen22\textfont2]current bounding box)}}`.

Comment: Not a bug, just that the picture is so small that some of the internal paths are adding to the bounding box.  The `clip width=5` probably isn't helping with that.

Comment: To address the non-question, the reason that `yshift` doesn't appear to have an effect is because that only shifts the path relative to the internal coordinates of the picture.  It does nothing to how TeX sees the picture from the outside, which is what matters for vertical alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problems here is that the bounding box of a tikzpicture might be larger than all of its contents, simply because of the way that TikZ computes bounding boxes - it goes for a "quick and easy" algorithm rather than a precise one.  This is nothing to do with the knots library.  What the knots library does which exacerbates this effect is that it mucks about with the curves quite a bit and this can all add to the bounding box.  Normally this doesn't matter, but because your diagrams are very small then it is having an effect.

The simplest way to deal with this is to tell TikZ explicitly what the bounding box should be.  Here, that's quite simple as there's an obvious containing rectangle.  Once we've done that then TikZ ignores everything else as far as the bounding box is concerned and then you can use whatever method you like to centre the picture, whether that is via the `baseline` key or just the `vcenter` command as in your original code.  The `vcenter` has the simplicity of not having to calculate things explicitly, whereas the `baseline` option offers you more control.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/684222/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  shapes, 
%  decorations, % <-- loaded by decorations.markings
  arrows.meta, 
  decorations.markings, 
  bending, 
  knots, 
  hobby, 
%  spath3, % <-- loaded by knots
%  intersections % <-- loaded by knots
}

\newcommand{\KP}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline=-\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]
        #1
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\KPthirtyoneone}{
  \KP{
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (.6,.6);
    \begin{knot}[
      flip crossing=2,
      consider self intersections = true,
      clip width = 5,
      ignore endpoint intersections=false,
    ]
    \draw[scale=0.6, line width=0.6pt] (0,1) .. controls (0.5,0.8) .. (1,1);
    \strand[scale=0.6, line width=0.6pt, looseness=1.4] (0,0) to [out=0,in=0] (0.5,0.7) to [out=180,in=180] (1,0);
    \end{knot}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[\Bigl\langle\vcenter{\hbox{\KPthirtyoneone}}\Bigr\rangle\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Centred kauffman bracket]

Comment: Is there a way to tell TikZ to use the precise algorithm to calculate the bounding boxes instead of the quick and dirty one?

Comment: On a related note, thank you so much for your packages. They were of great use to me; it would have been impossible for me to learn the insides of tikz well enough and create the knot diagrams without these packages.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis You're welcome!  I make these packages to be useful to me, and publish them in the hope that they'll be useful to others, so it's always nice to hear that they are.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

[image]

(`\alpha` and `\beta` are added that baseline can be seen)

- I assume that content of `\KP` can be any pictures with with different baseline positions, I suggest to add option for settings of `tikzpicture` baseline
- I would remove `\hspace{-6pt}\vcenter{\hbox{` at `\hspace{-6pt}\vcenter{\hbox{` inserting in equation and rather use manual setting of `\KPthirtyoneone` baseline positioning:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                bending, 
                decorations, decorations.markings, 
                hobby, 
                intersections, 
                knots, 
                shapes, spath3}
\newcommand{\KP}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=#1,
                    ]
    #2
\end{tikzpicture}%
                    }
\newcommand{\KPthirtyoneone}%
{
    \KP{1.4ex}{%
\begin{knot}[flip crossing=2, consider self intersections = true,
             clip width = 3, ignore endpoint intersections=false]
 \draw[scale=0.6, line width=0.6pt]
            (0,1) .. controls (0.5,0.8) .. (1,1);
 \strand[scale=0.6, line width=0.6pt, looseness=1.4]
            (0,0) to [out=0,in=0] (0.5,0.7) to [out=180,in=180] (1,0);
\end{knot}
        }
}
\begin{document}
\[
\alpha
\Bigl\langle
    \beta
    \KPthirtyoneone
\Bigr\rangle
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot part of the code. I copy-paste thing for sure :)

Comment: @JuanCastaño, you are right! Corrected now.

Comment: Now it's perfect!! +1

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer.